# CSS dot leaders with both sides left-aligned

Tags: html, css

I am converting XML to HTML using XSLT 3. One section requires two columns to be separated by dot leaders, but unlike most of the answers here, the second column has to be left-aligned, not right-aligned. I am trying to do this with pure CSS. I can change the HTML structure since I'm generating it.

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

The columns could have wrapping text.

[image: wrapped text]

Current undesirable output:

[image: Current output]

```css
.centerChallenge {
  font-size: 14pt;
  line-height: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.challenge-container {
  display: flex;
}

.challenge-container::after {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  content: " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ";
  flex: 1;
  height: 1em;
}

.right-indent-p {
  margin-right: 0.8em;
}

.response {
  order: 3;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex: 2;
}

.challenge p,
.response p {
  margin-bottom: 8pt;
  margin-top: 0pt;
font-family: "Courier New",monospace;
}
```

```html
    <div class="centerhead2">Pre-ride inspection</div>
    <div>
      <div class="centerChallenge">Brakes</div>
      <div>
        <div class="title">Levers</div>
        <div class="challenge-container">
          <div class="challenge">
            <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">1.</span>Levers</p>
          </div>
          <div class="response">
            <p>Approximately 1 inch of travel before engagement</div>
        </div>
        <div class="challenge-container">
          <div class="challenge">
            <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">2.</span>Levers</p>
          </div>
          <div class="response">
            <p>Space between lever and handlebar when fully pulled</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="centerChallenge">Wheels</div>
      <div class="challenge-container">
        <div class="challenge">
          <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">1.</span>Wheels</p>
        </div>
        <div class="response">
          <p>No loose bearings</div>
      </div>
      <div class="challenge-container">
        <div class="challenge">
          <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">2.</span>Wheels</p>
        </div>
        <div class="response">
          <p>True</div>
      </div>
      <div class="challenge-container">
        <div class="challenge">
          <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">3.</span>Spokes</p>
        </div>
        <div class="response">
          <p>Not broken</div>
      </div>
      <div class="caseCond" style="margin-left:7mm">If Spokes not broken</div>
      <div class="challenge-container">
        <div class="challenge">
          <p style="margin-left:14mm"><span class="right-indent-p">4.</span>Spokes</p>
        </div>
        <div class="response">
          <p>Tight</div>
      </div>
      <div class="challenge-container">
        <div class="challenge">
          <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">5.</span>Axel Nuts</p>
        </div>
        <div class="response">
          <p>Tight</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="centerChallenge">Headset</div>
      <div class="challenge-container">
        <div class="challenge">
          <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">1.</span>Headset bearings</p>
        </div>
        <div class="response">
          <p>Tight</div>
      </div>
    </div>
<div>
                     <div class="centerChallenge">Computer</div>
                     <div class="challenge-container">
                        <div class="challenge">
                           <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">1.</span>Computer Display</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="response">
                           <table>
                              <col style="column-width: 30mm">
                              <col style="column-width: 30mm">
                              <tbody>
                                 <tr class="captionRow">
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ff0000;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">ALTITUDE</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ffffff;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">0 miles</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr class="captionRow">
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ff0000;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">SPEED</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ffffff;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">0 mph</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr class="captionRow">
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ff0000;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">DISTANCE</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ffffff;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">0 miles</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                           <table>
                              <col style="column-width: 30mm">
                              <col style="column-width: 30mm">
                              <tbody>
                                 <tr class="captionRow">
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ff9900;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">SPEED</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ffffff;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">0 mph</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr class="captionRow">
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ff9900;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">DISTANCE</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       <div class="caption" style="background-color:#ffffff;width:30mm;">
                                          <div class="captionLine">0 miles</div>
                                       </div>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
```

If I add to the CSS:

```
.challenge {
        flex:1;
        }
```

The dot leaders line up well, but then it might cause inelegant wrapping in the first column.
[image: current ouput2]

Comment: Some little advice, as the spaces are important here, try to use a monospace font.

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet. It makes it easier to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a background image to create a repeating set of dots. This allows the element to be flexible. Have it inside a flex layout of the `.challenge` element, so that it can fill the remaining space left over by the text. Add a `flex-basis` to `.challenge` that you deem suitable (since you mentioned you did not want the first column to wrap).

```css
.centerChallenge {
  font-size: 14pt;
  line-height: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.challenge-container {
  display: flex;
}

.challenge {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.challenge::after {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: baseline;
  height: 1em;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 10 3'%3E%3Ccircle cx='1' cy='1' r='1'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") repeat-x bottom / auto 3px;
  content: "";
}

.right-indent-p {
  margin-right: 0.8em;
}

.response {
  order: 3;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex: 2;
}

.challenge p,
.response p {
  margin-bottom: 8pt;
  margin-top: 0pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerhead2">Pre-ride inspection</div>
<div>
  <div class="centerChallenge">Brakes</div>
  <div>
    <div class="title">Levers</div>
    <div class="challenge-container">
      <div class="challenge">
        <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">1.</span>Levers</p>
      </div>
      <div class="response">
        <p>Approximately 1 inch of travel before engagement</div>
    </div>
    <div class="challenge-container">
      <div class="challenge">
        <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">2.</span>Levers</p>
      </div>
      <div class="response">
        <p>Space between lever and handlebar when fully pulled</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="centerChallenge">Wheels</div>
  <div class="challenge-container">
    <div class="challenge">
      <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">1.</span>Wheels</p>
    </div>
    <div class="response">
      <p>No loose bearings</div>
  </div>
  <div class="challenge-container">
    <div class="challenge">
      <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">2.</span>Wheels</p>
    </div>
    <div class="response">
      <p>True</div>
  </div>
  <div class="challenge-container">
    <div class="challenge">
      <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">3.</span>Spokes</p>
    </div>
    <div class="response">
      <p>Not broken</div>
  </div>
  <div class="caseCond" style="margin-left:7mm">If Spokes not broken</div>
  <div class="challenge-container">
    <div class="challenge">
      <p style="margin-left:14mm"><span class="right-indent-p">4.</span>Spokes</p>
    </div>
    <div class="response">
      <p>Tight</div>
  </div>
  <div class="challenge-container">
    <div class="challenge">
      <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">5.</span>Axel Nuts</p>
    </div>
    <div class="response">
      <p>Tight</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="centerChallenge">Headset</div>
  <div class="challenge-container">
    <div class="challenge">
      <p style="margin-left:7mm"><span class="right-indent-p">1.</span>Headset bearings</p>
    </div>
    <div class="response">
      <p>Tight</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the `flex-basis` of `.challenge` to 25% and it's working great, thank you. I added extra `html` content to my question because sometimes the response `div` contains a table, and I couldn't get it to line up with the rest of the right-hand `div`s. I tried to replace my css in the code snippet with yours but I was creating formatting errors. Could you add that last `div` that starts with `<div class="centerChallenge">Computer</div>` to your answer?